# xcode: self error message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have insert an action when the button is pressed; the code is:

```
  [UIView transitionWithView:self.btnCardFront1 duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                    animations:^{
                        [self.btnCardFront1 setAlpha:0.0];
                        [self.btnCardBack1 setAlpha:1.0];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished){}
     ];
```

I would like insert this code into the function but is return this error:
Use of undeclared identifier 'self'

How can do replace self with the my element?
Thanks

Comment: Functions don't have a `self` argument unless you give it one. Methods do... where exactly are you trying to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to put self there anyway it would work still if self wasn't there.

Answer (score 2):

```
 __block <MySelfType class> *blocksafeSelf = self;

  [UIView transitionWithView:blocksafeSelf duration:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                    animations:^{
                        [blocksafeSelf setAlpha:0.0];
                        [blocksafeSelf setAlpha:1.0];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished){}
     ];
```